# Include Rails Index scaffold in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry if this has been asked - i looked but couldnt find.

I'm trying to put the following code into a partial:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.id %>'>
   <img src='<%= product.image_1 %>'/>
   <%= product.title %>
   <%= product.image_2 %>
 <% end %>
```

But can't make it work - can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: And what is not working here?

Comment: Remove the single quote and greater than sign `'>` from `<%= product.id %>'>`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling your partial you need to provide the `@products` variable

```
<%= render partial: 'your_partial', locals: {products: @products} %>
```

In your partial:

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.id %>
  <img src='<%= product.image_1 %>'/>
  <%= product.title %>
  <%= product.image_2 %>
<% end %>
```

A better way to do it would be just to pass the collection into the partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'your_partial', collection: @products %>
```

Then create the `_product` partial with the following code:

```
<%= product.id %>
<%= image_tag(product.image_1) %> 
<%= product.title %>
<%= product.image_2 %>
```

Comment: This looks right to me but when I implement it nothing shows up. The div is still empty for some reason, any idea why that might be? Thanks for your help!

Comment: We need more info about your code. Maybe the collection is empty. What code do you have in your controller? And did it work without using partials?